# Call a global function

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I come to you because I do not know how to access two different controllers to a global function.

I try to access a generic function that should be called two different controllers. The disconnect feature allows you to disconnect from the application, but also reset the global variables.

1. controller_1 and controller_2:

   ```
   function CONTROLLER_1 ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.disconnect = function() {
             // RESET $rootScope variable
             $rootScope.var1 = 0;
             $rootScope.var2 = 0;
             etc...
        };
   }

   function CONTROLLER_2 ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.disconnect = function() {
             // RESET $rootScope variable
             $rootScope.var1 = 0;
             $rootScope.var2 = 0;
             etc...
        };
   }
   ```
2. I would like something like this:

   ```
   function CONTROLLER_1 ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.disconnect = function() {
             //CALL GLOBAL_METHOD
        }
   }

   function CONTROLLER_2 ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.disconnect = function() {
             //CALL GLOBAL_METHOD
        }
   }  


   My GLOBAL_METHOD {
        // RESET $rootScope variable
        $rootScope.var1 = 0;
        $rootScope.var2 = 0;
        etc... 
   }
   ```

Is it possible to have a similar solution in this case? 
If I'm not precise enough, do not hesitate to ask me for more information

Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes it is possible, i suggest to make a plunkr or jsfiddle to make your solution to work first, then pin point your question. If you provide a working demo, the answer would be in 10 min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you should use a service for that:

I can see two solutions:

1°) Since each controllers inherit from rootScope, you can define disconnect function on rootScope you will be able to call disconnect automatically:

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.disconnect = function() {
        $rootScope.var1 = 0;
        $rootScope.var2 = 0;
    };
}]);

angular.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    // Disconnect function is already define
    $scope.applyDisconnect = function() {
        $scope.disconnect(); // Or $rootScope.disconnect();
    };
}]);

angular.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    // Disconnect function is already define
}]);
```

Be careful, you should not redefine disconnect function.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37cMw/2

2°) Use a dedicated service and inject it in your controllers:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('DisconnectService', ['$rootScope' function($scope) {
    this.disconnect = function() {
        $rootScope.var1 = 0;
        $rootScope.var2 = 0;
    };
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'DisconnectService', function($scope, service) {
    $scope.disconnect = function() {
        service.disconnect();
    };
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', 'DisconnectService', function($scope, service) {
    $scope.disconnect = function() {
        service.disconnect();
    };
}]);
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFvyj/

Second solution is my favourite since you don't pollute rootScope namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! Add the method to the .run of your module

```
angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope) {
 $rootScope.GLOBAL_METHOD = function() {
  //YOUR STUFF    
 })
})
```

And you can call this method from every controller like this:

```
$rootScope.GLOBAL_METHOD();
```

So in your case:

```
function CONTROLLER_1 ($scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.disconnect = function() {
          $rootScope.GLOBAL_METHOD();
     }
}

function CONTROLLER_2 ($scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.disconnect = function() {
          $rootScope.GLOBAL_METHOD();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the provided solution by user2874153 would probably work, it's best to avoid polluting the `$rootScope`. To share functions between controllers you should create a service.

You should also avoid declaring controllers in the global namespace, and should use the `angular.module` syntax instead (see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-object, the part where it says '**NOTE:** ').

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('OneCtrl', function ($scope, SharedService) {
    SharedService.doSomething();
  });

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('TwoCtrl', function ($scope, SharedService) {
    SharedService.doSomething();
  });

angular.module('myApp')
  .service('SharedService', function () {
    return {
      doSomething: function () {
        // do something here.
      }
    };
  });
```